# Can I post in facebook user wall and facebook fan page automatically when user is not active?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a requirement that on a certain time a corn will run and a big numbers of facebook pages and facebook user  profiles , and it would be automatic , no users will be active may be that time ! is that possible ?

Comment: As per my knowledge facebook may not provide this feature ! :(

Comment: can I post in facebook users wall and fan page wall with out api login in facebook ? I thought the queston was clear !

Comment: Without login? Yes, if you have the `access token` of the user, else no!

Comment: so how this can be handled ?any suggestion ?

Comment: but access token cant be used when a user logs out right ? if a user logins in today and he sets in system that his post will be automatically posted in facebook after 3 days ? if I save access token of that time , will that work anyway ?

Answer (score 1):

If a user authorized your app once, you can get the `long-lived token` (expiry: 60 days), and then use this to do actions on the user's behalf at any later time (till the token is expired- you'll have to refresh the token in that case)

Here's how you can exchange the normal access token with the long-lived token: [Expiration and Extending Tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#extending)

And to refresh the long-lived token, you have to repeat the same procedure again, by logging-in the user to your app again.